# Conflict installing Vispy with Python 3.5 in Anaconda3

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, vispy

```
conda install -c anaconda vispy=0.4.0.106.gf8a69d0
```

was [recommended by Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/vispy), but gave conflict on my Python 3.5
because current Vispy package supports only Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3 and 3.4.

Just trying Vispy as a newbie learner. Should I...

1. Be patient for a new Vispy release supporting Python 3.5
2. Force it *somehow* to install with Python 3.5
3. Config new Anaconda environment for Python 3.4

Comment: Seems like it's a known issue and they are working on it: [ContinuumIO](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/655)